# 'cygpath: not found' & 'exec: cmd: not found' for Pyenv on Windows WSL 2

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, pyenv

I have been trying to get Tensorflow to recognize my GPU within WSL 2. However, I believe that is largely irrelevant for the problem I am having right now.

Whenever I try to run the `pyenv` command within WSL I get the following error:

```bash
/mnt/c/Users/USER/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin/pyenv: 3: cygpath: not found
/mnt/c/Users/USER/.pyenv/pyenv-win/bin/pyenv: 3: exec: cmd: not found
```

Pyenv does work outside of the WSL environment.

Here are the details of my environment:

```bash
pyenv - 3.1.1
WSL Kernel - 5.15.133.1-1
WSL version - 2.0.9.0
Windows 10
Windows Version - 10.0.19045.3693
```

What can I do to make pyenv work inside WSL?

Comment: what does the command `which python` return? maybe you want to run `alias python=/usr/bin/python3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that my WSL environment was referring to the pyenv version installed on windows and not the pyenv version installed within WSL (ubuntu).

Installing pyenv in WSL and setting the correct path should help. It can be done like this:

```bash
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
```

Then add the next bit of code to your `~/.bashrc` and change the {USER} variable to your own username.

```bash
export PATH="/home/USER/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

For more details on installing pyenv in WSL Ubuntu, see [here](https://www.techtronic.us/install-python-pyenv-on-wsl-ubuntu/).

---

p.s. If you get a 'permission denied' error with cygpath and exec:cmd, see [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2026#issuecomment-1485529375).